# Processing form elements in magento

Tags: forms, magento

Is there any built-in way for processing forms such as validating user input...etc in magento ?(such as any libray or something) or do we have to write it our way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your own processing and validation with Zend_Validate. Magento provides only frontend form validation (look at js/prototype/validation.js) but most methods are similar to zend rules.

Answer (score 0):

There is using JavaScript. I Do Not have a running Magento Version here, but refer to this: 
http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/magento-forms-prototype-javascript-validation.html

Comment: That is only client side, that can be done with any javascript library. I am asking about the server side validation and all

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento zend validation for example

```
 if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
```

This is for validating email address, you can put this in your save action.
 for validating not empty field you can try this.

```
 if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['something']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
```